# Applying AC to a DC relay coil

Tags: relay, ac

I want to use a 24 V DC relay with 24 V AC. Will the relay stop working? Is it safe to do it this way?

Comment: Not all DC relays are equal. You have a data sheet available?

Comment: no i do not have a datasheet

Comment: Nobody can help you properly without a data sheet and the part number you gave on your previous question cannot be found on google. Do some work!

Comment: Relays are typically designed with coils that work with either one of AC or DC voltage. So you  should not try to use one component in place of the other one.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, where's the fun in that? ;^) See below.

Comment: @ Ricardo, PeterJ, Daniel Grillo, Andy aka, Null:  It's perfectly clear what the OP is asking, which is whether a relay with a DC rated coil can be used with  AC excitation. Several answers were given which address the question and provide solutions from a design point of view so, in all fairness, the question shouldn't have been put on hold and should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Add a bridge rectifier and it should work OK.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM9a4P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can use four diodes or a bridge rectifier which may be neater.

[Update after comments]

**Capacitor** is not required.
Provided no smoothing capacitor is added the rectified 24 V AC will be have wave rectified 24 V RMS (ignoring diode losses). The heating effect in the coil of 24 V RMS is exactly the same as 24 V DC so no problem there.

Addition of a capacitor will result in slow drop-out and slow opening of the contacts. If the load is significant relative to the contact rating then arcing and premature failure will occur.

Addition of a capacitor will also result in higher DC voltage - approaching DC peak - and this will overheat the coil. Half-wave rectification requires addition of a capacitor which is a bad idea as discussed above.

**Relay chatter** isn't a problem because

- The coil inductance tends to keep the current flowing to some extent.
- The inertia of the armature keeps everything in position.
- Maybe a little residual magnetism in the armature circuit helps a little too. Note that DC relays usually have a little stop pin or 'bump' to prevent them making a really good closed loop magnetic circuit - otherwise residual magnetism might be enough to hold the relay closed when power is removed.

**Reverse diodes** to protect the bridge rectifier aren't required as the function is provided by the bridge itself.

Comment: Are you sure that the peak voltage won't damage it?

Comment: The bridge will work just fine, but you'll need the catch diode across the coil just to make sure you don't damage the bridge.

Comment: @Andyaka: As long as he doesn't smooth the output of the bridge with a BFC, 24RMS = 24DC.

Comment: @EMFields what about the relay chattering due to the rectified AC?

Comment: @Andyaka:  Even at 50Hz, there's enough inductance in the coil that there's not enough time for the current to fall below the drop-out value before before it builds up again.  Plus, the catch diode slows down the coil's "discharge" and there's the mechanical inertia of the armature helping out.  And, since the voltage peaks are right around 34 volts there's that nice "kick" every 10 milliseconds. ;)  I've used it a lot and I've never had one chatter yet.

Comment: @Andyaka - A full-wave rectified 50 Hz AC will have a lowest frequency component of 100 Hz. Mechanical relays (particularly power relays) which can operate at 100 Hz are few and far between.

Comment: @EMFields, the bridge will act as the catch diode(s) from the bottom to the top of the coil.

Comment: @EMFields, there's still an abrupt turn-off of the supply but as long as the switch is outside of the bridge there won't be a high voltage spike on the contacts. Since it's AC it's unlikely that we'd use a transistor circuit anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Using half rectifier (One Diode with a capacitor 200uF) can eliminate the peak voltage/current risk, capacitor will smooth the output (somehow) and keep your relay active as well you will be able to drive DC relay with AC input.

Comment: The capacitor will result in slow drop-out and slow opening of the contacts. If the load is significant relative to the contact rating then arcing and premature failure will occur.

Answer (score -2):

If you are going to use 24v Relay use half wave rectifier (single diode and capacitor accordingly eg. 220µF/63V)

If you go for bridge rectifier voltage output will be more due to peak wave of sine wave ((Vout=24*1.414)-1.4=32V). So it will damage the relay.

Comment: Incorrect. If no capacitor is used the voltage of the rectified 24 V AC will be 24 V RMS which will have the same heating power as 24 V DC. Your capacitor idea will result in slow drop-out and slow opening of the contacts. If the load is significant relative to the contact rating then arcing and premature failure will occur.

Comment: Ya. I accept that. But,If no capacitor mean  in low frequency time relay will fluctuate due to zero crossing nature of sine wave.

Comment: You're forgetting that the coil has inductance which will tend to keep the current going. The armature also has inertia. The combination of both will keep the relay energised and I would be surprised if you could hear a hum or buzz from it.